# get variable from external js file

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to access a variable value in a script in my HTML file from a external javascript function....Something looking like this:

In my HTML page I have this:

```
<div  id="jsmolwindow" style="display:none;">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var scrt_var = "bucky.mol"; 
openPage = function() {
location.href = "javascript:Jmol.script(jmolApplet0,'load  "+scrt_var+"')";
}
</script>
<a href ="javascript:openPage()"><FONT COLOR="BLACK">View 3D Molecule</FONT></a>
<script type="text/javascript">
jmolApplet0 = Jmol.getApplet("jmolApplet0", Info);
</script>
</div>
```

That is displaying the image in scrt_var here bucky.mol.

Now I would want scrt_var to be "read" from a value defined in a external js file looking like that:

```
ui.onClick_exec_optimizer=function()
{
ui.showDialog('CARunning');
function GetAdress(){
return "bucky.mol";}
```

How can I link GetAdress and scrt_var ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the solution:

In html:

```
<div  id="jsmolwindow" style="display:none;">
<a href="#" id="mylink"><FONT COLOR="BLACK">View 3D Molecule</FONT></a>
<script type="text/javascript">
jmolApplet0 = Jmol.getApplet("jmolApplet0", Info);
</script>
 </div>
```

In js file:

```
ui.onClick_exec_optimizer=function()
{
var scrt_var = "bucky.mol";
document.getElementById("mylink").href = "javascript:Jmol.script(jmolApplet0,'load  "+scrt_var+"')";
}
```

That works fine.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Write the HTML script also in separate .js file. and in your HTML `<head>` do like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="first.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="second.js"></script>
```

now you can read any variable across any file. simple